# Read alerts in HTML unit

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am working on HTML unit with Java to read HTML pages. I have a scenario where I have to read messages from the popup/ alert window. I have an index page `page = form.getInputByName("index").click();`

After I click on the index page I get the response page. But before that I get an alert some thing like

[image]

I want to read the above message and then proceed with ok.

> I tried with alert handlers like `

```
ConfirmHandler okHandler = new ConfirmHandler(){
                @Override
                  public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
                      System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> message--"+message);
                         return true;
                            }


            };
            webClient.setConfirmHandler(okHandler);`
```

But this is not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the CollectingAlertHandler instead:

```
CollectingAlertHandler alertHandler = new CollectingAlertHandler();
webClient.setAlertHandler(alertHandler);

/*Your browsing codes here*/

List<String> alertmsgs = new ArrayList<String>();   
alertmsgs = alertHandler.getCollectedAlerts();
```

Then you can use the message obtained as you want. Reminder: You do not need to click the OK button.

Comment: If you have an "Ok" / "Cancel" alert, how do you specify which button to click?  How do you get the resulting page after you dismiss the alert?